# Find the derivative of the following by definition: $f(x,y)=(x^3, xy^2-y^2)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

$$f(x,y)=(x^3, xy^2-y^2)$$

So with these types of functions the derivative is $f'(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
        \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} \\
        \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y} \\
        \end{pmatrix}$
 where here in this example $f_1=x^3$ and $f_2=xy-y^2$, now what I don't know is how to get $$f'(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
        3x^2 & 0 \\
        y^2 & 2xy-2y \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$
by definition $$f(x+h, y+k)-f(x,y)=...$$ I don't know how to calculate this.. My try is :
$$f(x+h, y+k)-f(x,y)=...\\ =(3x^2h+3xh^2+h^3,2xyk+xk^2+hy^2+2yhk+hk^2-2yk-k^2)...? $$

My definition of differentiability:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed vector spaces upon the same field $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ and $U$ an open set in $X$. For a function $f:U \to Y$ it is said to be differentiable in point $x \in U$ if there exists a continuous linear map $A_x:X \to Y$ such that:
$$f(x+h)-f(x)=A_xh+R(h)$$ where $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{R(h)}{\|h\|}=0. \text{ or } R(h)=o(h)$$

$$A_x$$ is the derivative, that has to be linear and I have to prove that $R(h)=o(h)$

Comment: No you don't want $f(x+h,y+k)$ you want to do them one at a time, so $f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)$ and $f(x,y+k)-f(x,y)$.

Comment: But how? I don't understand, could you abbreviate ?

Comment: For example, $\frac{\partial{f_2}}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(xy-y^2) = x - 2y$

Comment: What definition of derivative are you using?

Comment: @GitGud I updated

Comment: Im playing the Timberwolves tommorow.

Comment: what you were doing is fine to calculate the Frechet derivative. It will be the linear terms in $h$ and $k$.

Comment: Id really appreciate if you could type that up. :)

Comment: sure. No problem.

Comment: You should have $f_2=xy^2-y^2$ based on your original function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x+h, y+k)-f(x,y)=...\\ =(3x^2h+3xh^2+h^3,2xyk+xk^2+hy^2+2yhk+hk^2-2yk-k^2)...? $$
is what you calculated. On examination of this we identify
$$f(x+h, y+k)-f(x,y)=...\\ = \underbrace{(3x^2h,2xyk+hy^2-2yk)}_{linear \ in \ h  \ and \ k}+(3xh^2+h^3,xk^2+2yhk+hk^2-k^2) $$
The part with the underbrace is $Df(x,y)(h,k)$ and the remaining piece rescaled by $\frac{1}{||(h,k)||}$ can be shown to vanish as $(h,k) \rightarrow (0,0)$. A bit more about the linear piece:
$$ Df(x,y)(h,k) = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}3x^2 & 0 \\ y^2 & 2xy-2y \end{array}\right]
\left[ \begin{array}{c} h \\ k \end{array}\right]$$
which you should be able to see that:
$$ Df(x,y)(h,k) = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \partial_x f_1 & \partial_y f_1 \\ \partial_x f_2 & \partial_y f_2 \end{array}\right]
\left[ \begin{array}{c} h \\ k \end{array}\right] $$
given $f = (f_1,f_2)$

Comment: See page 78 for an example with even more details which is very similar: http://www.supermath.info/AdvancedCalculus13.pdf